# Android MLKit scan QRcode only on center of screen

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I implemented firebase MLKit to scan QRCode, it is scanning, but it is scanning all QRcode on screen.
I need to scan only QRCode that are captured on the center (has arrow ImageView on the center), how can I do it?

I tried to crop on the Analisys function (inside ***analysisUseCase?.setAnalyzer***)

***imageProxy.cropRect()***

I tried to crop on the ***processImageProxy*** function.
But with no success, I think that I can't crop with this

```
class QrcodeScanner(
        private val onQrCapture: Barcode.() -> Unit,
        private val onFailure: Throwable.() -> Unit,
        private val lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner,
        private val context: Context,
        private val previewView: PreviewView
) {

    private var cameraSelector: CameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
            .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
            .build()
    private var cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider? = null
    private var previewUseCase: Preview? = null
    private var analysisUseCase: ImageAnalysis? = null

    fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture =
                ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(context)
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(
                {
                    runCatching {
                        val provider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
                        cameraProvider = provider
                        startPreview()
                        startAnalysis()
                    }.onFailure {
                        onFailure(it)
                    }
                },
                ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context)
        )
    }

    private fun startPreview() {
        if (previewUseCase != null) {
            cameraProvider?.unbind(previewUseCase)
        }

        previewUseCase = Preview.Builder()
                .setTargetRotation(previewView.display.rotation)
                .build()
        previewUseCase?.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)

        runCatching {
            cameraProvider?.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner,
                    cameraSelector,
                    previewUseCase
            )
        }.onFailure {
            onFailure(it)
        }
    }

    private fun startAnalysis() {
        val options = BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
             .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE)
             .build()
        val barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient(options)

        if (cameraProvider == null) {
            return
        }
        if (analysisUseCase != null) {
            cameraProvider?.unbind(analysisUseCase)
        }

        analysisUseCase = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .setTargetRotation(previewView.display.rotation)
                .build()

        val cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

        analysisUseCase?.setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor, ImageAnalysis.Analyzer { imageProxy ->
            processImageProxy(barcodeScanner, imageProxy)
        })

        runCatching {
            cameraProvider?.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner,
                    cameraSelector,
                    analysisUseCase
            )
        }.onFailure {
            onFailure(it)
        }

    }

    @SuppressLint("UnsafeExperimentalUsageError")
    private fun processImageProxy(
            barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner,
            imageProxy: ImageProxy
    ) {
        runCatching {
            val img = imageProxy.image
            if (img != null) {
                val inputImage =
                        InputImage.fromMediaImage(img, imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)

                barcodeScanner.process(inputImage)
                        .addOnSuccessListener { barcodes ->
                            barcodes.forEach {
                                onQrCapture(it)
                            }
                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener {
                            onFailure(it)
                        }.addOnCompleteListener {
                            imageProxy.close()
                        }
            } else {
                throw Exception("Falha ao processar a imagem")
            }
        }.onFailure {
            onFailure(it)
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, you can look at my solution that I gave here stackoverflow.com/a/67348548/13300615. Mb it helps you to crop the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

imageProxy.cropRect() only put a metadata in the image, but not do the cropping operation. For static image, you could convert to bitmap, and crop. A better way is to filter out the results when you have all the returned barcode with the detected barcode boundingbox.

Within MLKit, we are adding supports for image cropping.

Comment: So I can't use the crop for this, I have to use another way. Because I don't take picture, I scan the QR live... But how I filter this result? To detect the QR code when the QR are on center of PreviewView (cam). I have no idea

Comment: What you can do now is to get the list of detected barcodes, and only handle (like show the detected results) for the barcode within the interested region. The boundingbox of each barcode could be obtained by Barcode#getBoundingBox().

Comment: Plese share the implementation for the mlkit barcode scanning

Answer (score 2):

You can amend `onSuccess()` in `BarcodeScannerProcessor` class to check the barcode's four corners position. If it is within scan region, return true from `onSuccess()`, as follows:

```java
protected void onSuccess(List<Barcode> barcodes, GraphicOverlay graphicOverlay) {
    if (barcodes.isEmpty()) {
        Log.v(MANUAL_TESTING_LOG, "No barcode has been detected");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < barcodes.size(); ++i) {
        Barcode barcode = barcodes.get(i);
        BarcodeGraphic barcodeGraphic = new BarcodeGraphic(graphicOverlay, barcode);

        // check whether within valid scan area, translateX and translateY is to convert to screen position in pixel
        if (barcode.getBoundingBox() != null &&
                withinScanArea(
                    barcodeGraphic.translateY(barcode.getBoundingBox().top),
                    barcodeGraphic.translateX(barcode.getBoundingBox().left),
                    barcodeGraphic.translateY(barcode.getBoundingBox().bottom),
                    barcodeGraphic.translateX(barcode.getBoundingBox().right)
                )
        ) {
            graphicOverlay.add(barcodeGraphic);

            if (barcode.getRawValue() != null && !barcode.getRawValue().isEmpty()) {
                exchangeScannedData.sendScannedCode(barcode.getRawValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`scanAreaTop`, etc. are local variables with values according to your scan view

```java
private boolean withinScanArea(float top, float left, float bottom, float right) {
    return top > scanAreaTop &&
           left > scanAreaLeft &&
           bottom < scanAreaBottom &&
           right < scanAreaRight;
}
```

Comment: What is `BarcodeGraphic` class?

Comment: BarcodeGraphic draws the detected barcode’s “raw value” and bounding box

Answer (score 0):

I have recently been working on the same issue and figured out how to accurately filter `imageProxy` and detect only those barcodes that are in a focused rectangle in the middle of the screen

I've created this repository for those who might need it in the future
https://github.com/javaherisaber/MLBarcodeScanner